# How are hashes with identical keys used to relate menu items with order item prices in the following tutorial?

Tags: ruby, hash

I am working on the problem of 'Orders and costs' https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/problems/155-restaurant. Problem Statement is:

> A restaurant has incoming orders for which you need to compute the
>   costs based on the menu.
>
> You might get multiple orders at times

There is a solution (See the Solution) below the exercise, that looks like this:

```
class Restaurant
  def initialize(menu)
    @menu = menu
  end

  def cost(*orders)
    orders.inject(0) do |total_cost, order|
      total_cost + order.keys.inject(0) {|cost, key| cost + @menu[key]*order[key] }
    end
  end
end
```

I do not understand the whole algorithm: I think so - in `def cost(*orders)` `total_cost` is cost of order. `key` is item, in this case: rice and noodle, but what is meaning of `@menu[key]*order[key]`, I can not guess.

Can anyone explain me this exercise, please?

Answer (score 1):

if

```
@menu = {'rice' => 3.00, 'beans' => 2.50}
order = {'rice' => 1, 'beans' => 2)
```

So

```
@menu['rice'] == 3.00
order['rice'] == 1
3.00 * 1 == 3

@menu['beans'] == 2.50
order['beans'] == 2
2.50 * 2 == 5.00
```

Thus total order is 8.00

`key` is just the key being passed into each hash lookup. The two hashes `order` and `@menu` both use the key `rice`, one relates `rice` to its price on the menu, the other relates it to the number of `rice` items in the order.

Answer (score 0):

As the exercise told you, orders are {:rice => 1, :noodles => 1} and {:rice => 2, :noodles => 2} and menu is {:rice => 3, :noodles => 2}

The `@menu[key]*order[key]` just multiplies each @menu with a given key with the order with the same key.

@menu[:rice] * orders[:rice] So for the first oder (:rice)

```
@menu[:rice] # => 3 multiplied with 3 (once from the first order, twice from the second)
```

Same for the :noodles

```
@menu[:noodles] # => 2 multiplied with 3 (once from the first order, twice from the second)
```

Results then in 9 for :rice and 6 for :noodles => total_costs = 15+